# How do I stop wireframe from appearing in texture paint mode

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I do not want the wireframe to be painted in as well. I have just started a new file with no previous changes, but every time I try to paint, the wireframe also appears in the image. This only happens in the 3d viewport, and not the UV editor.[image]